# How can I separate logs based on scheduled events in the osquery.conf file?

Tags: logging, configuration, osquery

Is it possible to break out the results log for osquery? Currently, every query is being lumped into osqueryd.results.log but I'd like to break out logging based on scheduled events. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
 {
  "options": {
    "config_plugin": "filesystem",
    "logger_plugin": "filesystem",
    "host_identifier": "hostname",
    "utc": "true"
  },
  "schedule": {
    "crontab": {
      "query": "SELECT * FROM crontab;",
      "interval": 100000,
      +"logger_path": "/var/log/osquery/crontab.log"

    },
    "file_events": {
      "query": "SELECT * FROM file_events;",
      "removed": false,
      "interval": 10,
      +"logger_path": "/var/log/osquery/file_events.log"
    }
  },
  "file_paths": {
    "homes": [
      "/home/%/.ssh/%%"
    ],
    "etc": [
      "/etc/%%"
    ]
  },
  "exclude_paths": {
    "resolv.conf.*": [
      "/etc/resolv.conf.%"
    ]
  },
  "decorators": {
    "load": [
      "SELECT uuid AS host_uuid FROM system_info;",
      "SELECT user AS username FROM logged_in_users ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality does not exist in osquery.

You have a couple of options:

1) Are the logs being fed into a logging pipeline? You could split them up within that pipeline.

2) Open a [feature request](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/new?template=Feature_Request.md) with the osquery project. No guarantees on what will be implemented, but that is a good way to open a discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'll just have to breakout the osqueryd.results.log file within logstash. On top of that, I'll definitely request this feature.